My express server is not saving the JWT in cookies
I'm trying to make a blog with react and express with sql but when I'm trying to save the JWT into a cookie the browser just don't save it, I don't get it because there is no error in the console or the browser, it returns a 200 and the login page redirects to main but doesn't save the cookie:
here is my login controller:
export const login = (req, res) => {
    //Check if the user exists
    const q = "SELECT username, password FROM blog.users WHERE username = ?;"
    db.query(q, [req.body.username], (err, [data])=>{
        if(err) return res.json(err);
        if(data === undefined) return res.status(404).json('User not found!');

        //Check password and generate jwt

        bcrypt.compare(req.body.password ,data.password)
            .then((passwordCheck)=>{
                if(!passwordCheck) return res.status(400).json('Wrong password');
                const {password, ...other} = data;
                jwt.sign({id: data.id}, 'chop_suey', (err, token)=>{
                    if(err){
                        console.log(err)
                        return res.status(500).json('')
                    }
                    res.cookie('access_token', 'eso brad', {
                        httpOnly: true,
                        secure: true,
                    }).status(200).json(other)
                });   
            })
            .catch((err)=>{
                console.log(err)
                return res.status(500).json('Server error: password check failed')
            })

        


    })
}

this is the index where I configured the cookie parser:
import express from 'express'
import authRoutes from "./routes/auth.js"
import userRoutes from "./routes/users.js"
import postRoutes from "./routes/posts.js"
import cookieParser from 'cookie-parser'


const app = express();
const port = 8800;

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:5173');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization');
    if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
        return res.sendStatus(204);
    }
    next();
});

app.use(express.json())
app.use(cookieParser())
app.use('/api/auth', authRoutes)
app.use('/api/users', userRoutes)
app.use('/api/posts', postRoutes)


app.listen(port, ()=>{
    console.log(`Servidor montado en el puerto ${port}`)
})

and the front:
import {useState} from 'react'
import {Link, useNavigate} from 'react-router-dom'
import axios from 'axios'

const Login = () => {

  const [inputs, setInputs] = useState({
    username: '',
    password: ''
  });

  let [err, setError] = useState(null);

  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const handleChange = e => {
    setInputs(prev=>({...prev, [e.target.name]: e.target.value}))
  }

  const handleClick = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()  
    try{
      await axios.post('http://localhost:8800/api/auth/login', inputs);
      setError(err = null)
      setTimeout(()=>{
        navigate("/")
      }, "1000");
    } catch(err){
      if(err){
        console.log(err)
        setError(err.response.data)  
      }
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="auth">
      <h1>Login</h1>
      <form>
        <input name="username" type="text" placeholder='Username' onChange={handleChange}/>
        <input name="password" type="password" placeholder='Password' onChange={handleChange}/>
        <button onClick={handleClick}>login</button>
        {err && <p>{err}</p>}
        <span>Don't you have an account? <Link to='/register'>register</Link></span>
      </form>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Login


I'll configure the secret kay for the JWT later in a environment variant :p
I just want that the JWT gets stored in a cookie on the browser for the session
